# Regular expression to replace same patterns with another string

Tags: mysql, regex, unix

I have a string below that I want to replace all `/data/.*/www` with `/www`.

> StackTrace::getCurrent() at
> /data/users/eaminz/www/flib/intern/scripts/insights/msis/workflows/messaging/MSISWorkFlowLoggerSingleton.php:102@r0\nMSISWorkFlowLoggerSingleton::errorWrongConfig()
> at
> /data/users/eaminz/www/flib/intern/insights/simplification/ads/codegen/api/business_insights/BusinessInsightsAPIMetricCodegen.php:89@r0\nBusinessInsightsAPIMetricCodegen::generateStorageCode()
> at
> /data/users/eaminz/www/flib/intern/insights/simplification/ads/codegen/api/business_insights/BusinessInsightsAPIMetricCodegen.php:40@r0\nBusinessInsightsAPIMetricCodegen::generateCode()
> at
> /data/users/eaminz/www/flib/intern/scripts/insights/msis/codegen/InsightsAPIMetricSimplificationScriptController.php:380@r0\nInsightsAPIMetricSimplificationScriptController->generateProductSpecificStorageCode()
> at
> /data/users/eaminz/www/flib/intern/scripts/insights/msis/codegen/InsightsAPIMetricSimplificationScriptController.php:285@r0\nInsightsAPIMetricSimplificationScriptController->genMetricCode()
> at
> /data/users/eaminz/www/flib/intern/scripts/insights/msis/codegen/InsightsAPIMetricSimplificationScriptController.php:200@r0\nInsightsAPIMetricSimplificationScriptController->genRunImpl()
> at
> /data/users/eaminz/www/flib/intern/scripts/insights/msis/codegen/InsightsAPIMetricSimplificationScriptController.php:113@r0\nInsightsAPIMetricSimplificationScriptController->genRun()
> at
> /data/users/eaminz/www/flib/intern/scripts/controller/ScriptController.php:189@r0\nScriptController->__genRunWithCommandLineArgs()
> at
> /data/users/eaminz/www/flib/intern/scripts/controller/ScriptController.php:111@r0\nScriptController::__genDispatch()
> at
> /data/users/eaminz/www/scripts/bin/phps_init.php:23@r0\nphps_init_entrypoint()
> at :0@r0\nClosure$__SystemLib\enter_async_entry_point() at
> :0@r0\nHH\Asio\join() at :0@r0\n__SystemLib\enter_async_entry_point()
> at :0@r0

So it should become something like the following:

> StackTrace::getCurrent() at
> /www/flib/intern/scripts/insights/msis/workflows/messaging/MSISWorkFlowLoggerSingleton.php:102@r0\nMSISWorkFlowLoggerSingleton::errorWrongConfig()
> at
> /www/flib/intern/insights/simplification/ads/codegen/api/business_insights/BusinessInsightsAPIMetricCodegen.php:89@r0\nBusinessInsightsAPIMetricCodegen::generateStorageCode()
> at

I tried `/data/.*[^/]www/` to find all the patterns but no use. Could someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: but where? what? give some real code and tell us where it was used? in mysql console? query? your question doesn't make any sense, mysql doesn't return stacktrace

Comment: \/data\/[^(www)]*www .. this will give the desired search pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`\/data\/.*?\/www`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZAEmvF/1)